# Active Directory - DNS entries missing after installation

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, active-directory

I've just installed active directory on a windows 2003 system, and installed DNS along with AD - but the DNS is missing a lot of important entries that mean the AD is not working.  This is a new domain in a new forest.

Looking in the DNS properties I can see the mydomain.local zone, which only contains an A record.  Uder that in the tree view I can see a folder called _msdcs, but the only entry here is a single NS entry with the server's IP address.

The _rcp, _udp, and other entries are all missing.

How can I recreate the DNS entries for this AD domain?

[edit]  This is a brand-new domain, there is only one system (the AD controller) and there are no other DNS servers the zone can be copied from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would be suspicious that the dcpromo did not run properly if you are missing those entries right after promoting the server, with it being the only server on the Domain. I'd be tempted to do a `dcpromo /demote` to destroy the domain and start again.

That being said.

And you found my suggestion as I was typing it.

In addition to the `netdiag /fix` you found. I would run a `dcdiag /e /fix` to verify the domain.

Answer (score 1):

On domain controller in new domain,

- make sure it is using proper DNS inside your active directory domain (same as you are viewing DNS entries on)
- make sure there are no alternative DNS servers specified
- ensure that network is up
- run following command on command line:

  ```
  ipconfig /registerdns
  ```

then restart netlogon service, and you should be good.

if you still are missing DNS after that, check errors in event log of DNS server and new domain controloler

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the netlogin service didn't help, but "netdiag /fix" identified the missing entries and recreated them.

```
DNS test . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Failed
    [FIX] re-register DC DNS entry '_ldap._tcp.mydomain.local.' on DNS server '127.0.0.1' succeed.
etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

The things I can think of that is worth checking are:

1. On your network card, did you specify itself as the DNS server? You must either put its IP address as the FIRST DNS server, or the loopback address, so that the system know which DNS server to go to to register its entries. (Or if you DNS server is a different system, point the DC's network card to that DNS server.)
2. In your DNS forward lookup zone, did you enable "Dynamic Updates" to either "Nonsecure and Secure" or "Secure Only"? A "None" setting will deny any updates to the zone and the entries will not be added.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution (proper procedure) is: in addition to having proper primary DNS setting at the NIC, don't create the forward lookup zone before promoting the AD-integrated DNS to a domain controller. It will be auto created with all related items after DC promotion. If additional forward lookup zone need to be created after the DNS became the DC, make sure to select "Store the zone in Active Directory".