# Active Directory - Nearly all DNS zones and entries are not created

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2016

This problem seems exactly the same as [question 73875](https://serverfault.com/questions/73875/active-directory-dns-entries-missing-after-installation) albeit for a different version of windows and I've tried the accepted answer to no avail, it seems that in my case the problem is not transient and creating the domain a second time changed nothing.

All entries are missing except one ns entry for the domain controller. This is a new server, up to date. It is also my first shot at AD, domains etc but I'm positive I've followed the guide everyone posts (including on technet) to the letter.

I provide a [screenshot of DNS Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBYa6.png).

```
C:\Users\Administrator.PDC>dcdiag /test:registerindns /dnsdomain:xxx /v
Starting test: RegisterInDNS
  DNS configuration is sufficient to allow this domain controller to dynamically register the domain controller Locator records in DNS.

  The DNS configuration is sufficient to allow this computer to dynamically register the A record corresponding to its DNS name.

  ......................... PDC passed test RegisterInDNS
```

I'm unable to properly understand the output of dcdiag DNS tests, except that delegation seems to be ok, but I include it as well.

```
C:\Users\Administrator.PDC>dcdiag /test:DNS /dnsdomain:mydomain /v

Directory Server Diagnosis

Performing initial setup:
Trying to find home server...
* Verifying that the local machine PDC, is a Directory Server.
Home Server = PDC
* Connecting to directory service on server PDC.
* Identified AD Forest.
Collecting AD specific global data
* Collecting site info.
Calling ldap_search_init_page(hld,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx,LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE,(objectCategory=ntDSSiteSettings),.......
The previous call succeeded
Iterating through the sites
Looking at base site object: CN=NTDS Site Settings,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx
Getting ISTG and options for the site
* Identifying all servers.
Calling ldap_search_init_page(hld,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx,LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE,(objectClass=ntDSDsa),.......
The previous call succeeded....
The previous call succeeded
Iterating through the list of servers
Getting information for the server CN=NTDS Settings,CN=PDC,CN=Servers,CN=Default-First-Site-Name,CN=Sites,CN=Configuration,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx
objectGuid obtained
InvocationID obtained
dnsHostname obtained
site info obtained
All the info for the server collected
* Identifying all NC cross-refs.
* Found 1 DC(s). Testing 1 of them.
Done gathering initial info.

Doing initial required tests

Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\PDC
  Starting test: Connectivity
     * Active Directory LDAP Services Check
     The host b144abfd-0418-478c-9056-b947bc9474ad._msdcs.mydomain could not be resolved to an IP address. Check the DNS server, DHCP, server name, etc.
     Got error while checking LDAP and RPC connectivity. Please check your firewall settings.
     ......................... PDC failed test Connectivity

Doing primary tests

Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\PDC
  Test omitted by user request: Advertising
  Test omitted by user request: CheckSecurityError
  Test omitted by user request: CutoffServers
  Test omitted by user request: FrsEvent
  Test omitted by user request: DFSREvent
  Test omitted by user request: SysVolCheck
  Test omitted by user request: KccEvent
  Test omitted by user request: KnowsOfRoleHolders
  Test omitted by user request: MachineAccount
  Test omitted by user request: NCSecDesc
  Test omitted by user request: NetLogons
  Test omitted by user request: ObjectsReplicated
  Test omitted by user request: OutboundSecureChannels
  Test omitted by user request: Replications
  Test omitted by user request: RidManager
  Test omitted by user request: Services
  Test omitted by user request: SystemLog
  Test omitted by user request: Topology
  Test omitted by user request: VerifyEnterpriseReferences
  Test omitted by user request: VerifyReferences
  Test omitted by user request: VerifyReplicas

  Starting test: DNS

     DNS Tests are running and not hung. Please wait a few minutes...
     See DNS test in enterprise tests section for results
     ......................... PDC passed test DNS

Running partition tests on : DomainDnsZones
  Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom
  Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

Running partition tests on : ForestDnsZones
  Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom
  Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

Running partition tests on : Schema
  Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom
  Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

Running partition tests on : Configuration
  Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom
  Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

Running partition tests on : bo
  Test omitted by user request: CheckSDRefDom
  Test omitted by user request: CrossRefValidation

Running enterprise tests on : mydomain
  Starting test: DNS
     Test results for domain controllers:

        DC: PDC.mydomain
        Domain: mydomain


           TEST: Authentication (Auth)
              Authentication test: Successfully completed

           TEST: Basic (Basc)
              Error: No LDAP connectivity
              The OS Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard (Service Pack level: 0.0) is supported.
              NETLOGON service is running
              kdc service is running
              DNSCACHE service is running
              DNS service is running
              DC is a DNS server
              Network adapters information:
              Adapter [00000000] Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter:
                 MAC address is 32:17:9C:64:E5:3A
                 IP Address is static
                 IP address: 123.456.789.16
                 DNS servers:
                    Warning:
                    127.0.0.1 (pdc.mydomain.) [Invalid]
                    Warning: adapter [00000000] Red Hat VirtIO Ethernet Adapter has invalid DNS server: 127.0.0.1 (pdc.mydomain.)
              Error: all DNS servers are invalid
              No host records (A or AAAA) were found for this DC
              The SOA record for the Active Directory zone was found
              The Active Directory zone on this DC/DNS server was found primary
              Root zone on this DC/DNS server was not found

           TEST: Forwarders/Root hints (Forw)
              Recursion is enabled
              Forwarders Information:
                 123.456.789.250 (<name unavailable>) [Valid]
                 123.456.789.4 (<name unavailable>) [Valid]

           TEST: Delegations (Del)
              Delegation information for the zone: mydomain.
                 Delegated domain name: _msdcs.mydomain.
                    DNS server: pdc.mydomain. IP:123.456.789.16 [Valid]

           TEST: Dynamic update (Dyn)
              Test record dcdiag-test-record added successfully in zone mydomain
              Test record dcdiag-test-record deleted successfully in zone mydomain

        TEST: Records registration (RReg)
           Error: Record registrations cannot be found for all the network adapters

     Summary of test results for DNS servers used by the above domain controllers:

        DNS server: 123.456.789.16 (pdc.mydomain.)
           1 test failure on this DNS server
           Name resolution is not functional. _ldap._tcp.mydomain. failed on the DNS server 123.456.789.16
           [Error details: 9003 (Type: Win32 - Description: DNS name does not exist.)]
           DNS delegation for the domain  _msdcs.mydomain. is operational on IP 123.456.789.16


        DNS server: 123.456.789.250 (<name unavailable>)
           All tests passed on this DNS server

        DNS server: 123.456.789.4 (<name unavailable>)
           All tests passed on this DNS server

     Summary of DNS test results:

                                        Auth Basc Forw Del  Dyn  RReg Ext
        _________________________________________________________________
        Domain: mydomain
           PDC                          PASS FAIL PASS PASS PASS FAIL n/a

     ......................... mydomain failed test DNS
  Test omitted by user request: LocatorCheck
  Test omitted by user request: Intersite
```

I add that this domain is being deployed for test/evaluation in an existing unix infrastructure, therefore the wizard complains about not being able to get a delegation. This is expected, however I already configured the delegation in my primary dns (tinydns) and dcdiag is ok with it. In my opinion it's not even part of the equation yet as the zones must exist in the pdc first but I may be wrong of course.

This is the relevant tinydns configuration.

```
&_udp.mydomain::pdc.mydomain:::
&_tcp.mydomain::pdc.mydomain:::
&_sites.mydomain::pdc.mydomain:::
&_msdcs.mydomain::pdc.mydomain:::
=pdc.mydomain:123.456.789.16:::
6pdc.mydomain:longipv6address:::
```

For testing purposes I disabled temporarily ipv6 on the pdc, I also set its only DNS server as 127.0.0.1 as shown on multiple guides. The firewall allows outbound traffic and all inbound from local networks (I also tried disabling temporarily the firewall, couldn't spot a difference). All tests are conducted on the pdc itself.

Answer (score -1):

Zones are created automatically when you install Active directory integrated DNS. In contrast, Zones and records are not created automatically when you install File-based DNS. It's normal that in a newly installed server you find it without record and zones since you have to start creating them. If this is gonna be a replicated server (you already have another) then it's a different story. If you need to ask a more specific question please do it. Hope it helps!

Comment: This is incorrect. You do not have to manually create the DNS records when creating an AD domain. The DCPROMO process creates the needed DNS records.

Comment: @joeqwerty thanks, that was my understanding too. Humberto, I don't need to add any more stuff than the domain creation itself should, my dns data is already handled by a unix server and I have already set the delegations for the zones AD should have created.

Comment: If your DNS is handled by UNIX servers then that's completely different from the question you link to. Please update your question and include the configuration of your UNIX DNS server.